# Шаблон для сообщений без склонений

Tags: выбор-слов, согласование

Приложению требуется генерировать сообщения о рейтинге пользователя в стране. 
Примерно такие:

> Василий Пупкин на 12345-м месте по России.
>   Чулпан Портная занимает 789-е место в рейтинге Сейшельских островов.

Мне нужно придумать шаблон для этого сообщения, причем такой, чтобы не склонять название страны.  Шаблоны для этих сообщений выглядели бы так:

> <имя_пользователя> на <номер_места>-м месте по <название_страны>.
>   <имя_пользователя> занимает <номер_места>-е место в рейтинге <название_страны>.

Но тут есть проблема. Приложение умеет вставлять данные в треугольные скобки. Но склонять приложение не умеет. Поэтому первый шаблон генерирует сообщение

> Василий Пупкин на 12345-м месте по Россия.

Что можно сделать?
Для того чтобы не склонять *имена пользователей* в сообщениях, обычно вставляют слово "пользователь", то есть:

> Получено сообщение от Чулпан Портной.
>   Василию Пупкину отправлено сообщение.

превращается в

> Получено сообщение от пользователя Чулпан Портная.
>   Пользователю Василий Пупкин отправлено сообщение.

Но что делать со страной, чтоб не склонять? Будет ли хорошо написать

> Василий Пупкин на 12345-м месте по стране Россия.

или

> Чулпан Портная занимает 789-е место в рейтинге страны Сейшельские острова.

Может, можно придумать лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы корректно избавиться от необходимости склонения, проще всего избавиться от синтаксиса. Помнится, был такой нехитрый тренерский приёмчик для развития честолюбия у начинающих спортсменов: входящего тренер громко объявлял по имени и фамилии, делал паузу и торжественно добавлял - Советский Союз! Работало, между прочим. Сделайте подобное: <имя_пользователя> : <страна> <флаг_страны> <место> "в национальном рейтинге".